# Automatically print PDF without confirmation on Android

Tags: android, pdf, printing

We're building an Android app to help print pdfs.  The app retrieves pdfs via api and we are greeted with the print preview screen after which we click the print button.

I want to skip the print preview screen and send the PDF to the printer automatically.

Any advice on if this is possible at all is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Android has no support for this. Whether there are any options for doing this via direct communication with the printer will depend on the printer.

Comment: You should think through your idea. Or just visit www.youarekidding.pr/10000000000page.pdf and then think about your requirement